# .Htaccess rewrite to username

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a beginner in php and primarily with htaccess part. It's pretty darn confusing.

So I have this file :-

```
www.domain.com/profile.php?username=my_username
```

How can I make the above accessible using only :-

```
wwww.domain.com/my_username
```

Any kind of directions would be helpful

Something that I tried :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: .htaccess and php have nothing to do with each other in this case, other than you're trying to hide something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these set of rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?username=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Says "Not Found".

I'm using a mac, if that helps.

Comment: .htaccess is located in the same directory as profile.php
Full url is :- http://localhost/foldername/profile.php

Comment: Your question doesn't mention presence of `foldername`. What happens when you enter `localhost/foldername/username` ?

Comment: When I load `localhost/foldername/username` it says :- Not Found

Comment: It's still the same. Not found.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: I don't think it's enabled. I entered some random text and loaded `profile.php?username=myusername` amd it loaded fine.

Comment: So I just enabled .htaccess from httpd.conf.
I removed all random text and only your solution is present. It still throws a 500 eror.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to know what is the error

Comment: Voila! the entire log is empty

Comment: That means you are not looking at right place. Every 500 error has an entry in Apache error.log

Comment: I deleted my log file and then recreated it.
Now apache ain't saving any logs into it.
Damn me

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?username=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file has to be given permission by apache to modify/override settings, depending on your host this might not be enabled by default.

As others have mentioned .htaccess isn't part of PHP it's a file that tells apache how to deal with certain request and what parts of the server are allow to be accessed along with other functionality.

You can achieve your desired result with rewritecond just make sure the Rewrite Engine is enabled.

Here is some more information about .htaccess https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757